# C#: capture fingerprint from integrated scanner built into laptop

Tags: c#, fingerprint, biometrics

.net 4.5.5

I have an HP EliteBook 8740w which has VFS451 Fingerprint Scanner built into it and it's working just fine. How can I capture fingerprints in c# for a way of authentication (I'm looking for a simple and working library)?

I found [SourceAFIS](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SourceAFIS/Tutorial) and installed it using NuGet but don't know what should I do to capture fingerprints when the user swipes his finger on the scanner.

Answer (score 2):

From looking around a bit it seems that HP laptops using this scanner also use some Digital Persona software, so you might try the Digital Persona SDK.  Its not free, though you may be able to find an old version somewhere.

For a more general solution for capturing fingerprint images using your laptop's built-in scanner, try [Neurotechnology's Free Fingerprint SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/free-fingerprint-verification-sdk.html) or [Graiule Biometric's SDK](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/fingerprint_sdk).  I've used both of these in C#, and both work well for capturing a fingerprint image using, which you can then process through SourceAfis.  Both also have extraction and matching functionality so you don't have to use another library if you choose not to.  Also, Free Fingerprint SDK comes with a lot of drivers for different scanning devices.  Your scanner isn't listed under supported devices, but it may be worth a try.  Graiule has their own driver which replaces the manufacturers driver, though I don't see your device listed there either.

Once you are able to capture a fingerprint image, then SourceAfis is great for extracting features and creating and matching fingerprint templates.